# Using custom delegate with the class derived from QTableView

Tags: qt, qtableview, qitemdelegate

I have derived a class from QTableView. and I have Promoted the Widget QTableViewto the derived class in Qt creator. and try to implement the Custom delegate in the derived class, which does not seem to work. But when I demote the QTableView Widget to QTableView. Custom delegate works.

I tried to go through a documentation but could not find any solution. Am I missing anything?

Update:

I have checked the Paint() method is called but not createEditor method.

You can find the code below.

Geometry.cpp (constructor of the class derived from QTableView)

```
Geometry::Geometry(QWidget *parent) :
    QTableView(parent)
{
   this->setAcceptDrops(true);
   this->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection);
   this->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
   this->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);

   grpModel = new QStandardItemModel();

   grpModel->setHorizontalHeaderItem(0,new QStandardItem ("Geometry part"));
   grpModel->setHorizontalHeaderItem(0,new QStandardItem ("Surface property"));
   this->setModel(grpModel);
}
```

MyDelegate.cpp (Definition of custom delegate)

```
QWidget* MyDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,     const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    //Definition
    this method is not called
}

void MyDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const
 {

   //definition

}

void MyDelegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
 //definition
}

 void MyDelegate::updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
 {
    editor->setGeometry(option.rect);
 }

 void MyDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,      const QModelIndex &index) const
 {
       QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter,option,index); // This method is called
 }
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{     
 ui->setupUi(this);

 ui->tableGeometry->setModel(grpModel); //tabelGeometry is promoted to Geometry
 comboDelegate = new MyDelegate();
 ui->tableGeometry->setItemDelegate(comboDelegate);
 }
```

Comment: You should clarify what exactly is not working. Show some SSCCE.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov: The problem is that, createEditor method is not called, but paint() method is called.

Comment: Are you sure, that your item is editable? See `setFlags` method.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov: You are right, I had set the flag to NoEditTriggers in the constructor of the derived class from QTabelView.

Comment: Do not add "solved" to *questions*. If you have a solution, post it as an answer to your own question. If the problem can't be reproduced anymore, delete the question. As it is, we have a "solved" question with no solution in sight.

Comment: Please do post the solution as explained by Kuba Ober.

Answer (score 3):

The solution was that

I have removed `this->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);` from the constructor of the class Geometry.cpp. What i have understood that delegate was attached but not called because Items must be editable for the delegate to be called.